# How to calculate "Standard deviation (STD)" by CDO?

Tags: cdo-climate

How can I calculate the temporal "Standard deviation" with cdo?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Have you read through the CDO user guide. It lists multiple ways to calculate standard deviation https://code.mpimet.mpg.de/projects/cdo/embedded/cdo.pdf#page128

Comment: you talk of obs and model, are you actually wanting the root mean square error between the two?  Usually standard model evaluation metrics are MAE, RMSE and anomaly correlation - perhaps you could clarify your question?

Comment: @AdrianTompkins  read the question as possibly about comparing variation between model and observations, but clarification would help.

Comment: @Khan can you clarify this question? If Rob's answer really solved your issue then you have a lot of superfluous info in your question that needs deleting and you should also write temporal standard deviation (i.e. not spatial).  My gut feeling was you were looking for a way to compare model to obs and thus wanted a spatial metric like RMSE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the standard deviation across all time steps and for each grid cell you would do the following:

```
cdo timstd infile outfile
```

Comment: Very well explained. Thank you so much for your kindness. I (new user) understand  from your question and I got my answer for your question.